# Omnet++/Inet: 2 lisp routers keep on boucing each other messages without being forwarded

Tags: mobile, router, omnet++, ppp, inet

In a Omnet++/Inet scenario I have a couple of LISP routers which are not able to communicate. I mean that `MapRequest` messages sent from `LISP router1` to `LISP router2` are not forwarded to a central network as expected, but `router2` sends back the message to `router1` and the following message error is generated

```
Setting source IP=192.168.0.7
INFO(lispRouter4): srcAddress=192.168.0.7, dstAddress=192.168.0.254
INFO: Source IP=192.168.0.7 address not in EID space.
Destination IP=192.168.0.254 address not in EID space.
Handing over packet to regular IPv4-routing
output interface is ppp0, next-hop address: <unspec>
** Event #26  T=0  MultiHomingNetwork.lispRouter1.networkLayer.arp (ARP,     id=109), on `LISPMapRegister-#1' (IPDatagram, id=263)
Packet (IPDatagram)LISPMapRegister-#1 arrived from higher layer, output   interface ppp0 is not broadcast, skipping ARP
** Event #27  T=0  MultiHomingNetwork.lispRouter2.networkLayer.arp (ARP,  id=185), on `LISPMapRegister-#2' (IPDatagram, id=264)
Packet (IPDatagram)LISPMapRegister-#2 arrived from higher layer, output interface ppp0 is not broadcast, skipping ARP
** Event #28  T=0  MultiHomingNetwork.lispRouter3.networkLayer.arp (ARP, id=233), on `LISPMapRegister-#3' (IPDatagram, id=265)
Packet (IPDatagram)LISPMapRegister-#3 arrived from higher layer, output  interface ppp0 is not broadcast, skipping ARP
** Event #29  T=0  MultiHomingNetwork.lispRouter4.networkLayer.arp (ARP,   id=307), on `LISPMapRegister-#4' (IPDatagram, id=266)
Packet (IPDatagram)LISPMapRegister-#4 arrived from higher layer, output  interface ppp0 is not broadcast, skipping ARP
```

---

I do not understand why this occurs because in the system I have another couple of lisp routers and they work perfectly as expected. So there must be an error in the `.irt` files I think. I have written the `.irt` files in a specular way compared to the working routers, changing only the IP address. I don't know what it means that *"interface ppp0 is not broadcast"*... Here are the files of the added routers:

**PITR2.irt**

```
ifconfig:

# interface 0 to router
name: ppp0  inet_addr: 192.168.0.6    MTU: 1500   Metric: 1
name: ppp1  inet_addr: 192.168.0.6    MTU: 1500   Metric: 1

ifconfigend.

route:

192.168.0.4    0.0.0.0       255.255.255.255 H 0 ppp0
192.168.0.7    0.0.0.0       255.255.255.255 H 0 ppp1
192.168.0.254  0.0.0.0       255.255.255.255 H 0 ppp0

routeend.
```

**lispRouter4.irt**

```
ifconfig:

# interface 0 to router
name: ppp0  inet_addr: 192.168.0.7    MTU: 1500   Metric: 1
name: ppp1  inet_addr: 192.168.0.7    MTU: 1500   Metric: 1
name: eth0  inet_addr: 132.187.7.1  Mask: 255.255.255.0  MTU: 1500   Metric: 1

ifconfigend.

route:

192.168.0.0    0.0.0.0      255.255.255.0 H 0 ppp0
132.187.7.0    0.0.0.0      255.255.255.0 H 0 eth0

routeend.
```

and finally these are the links in the .NED file:

```
lispRouter4: LISPRouter {
        parameters:
            routingFile = "lispRouter4.irt";
            @display("p=640,322");
 }

PITR2: LISPRouter {
        parameters:
            mapServerAddress = "mapServer";
            routingFile = "PITR2.irt";
            @display("p=442,314;is=n");
}

...
PITR2.pppg++ <--> ppLink <--> lispRouter4.pppg++;
```

Do you have any idea? 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the log, router `lispRouter4` sends a datagram to the destination address `192.168.0.254`. The router `PITR2` receives this datagram, check that any of his own addresses is not equal to destination address, therefore looks into own routing table and found the following entry:

```
192.168.0.254  0.0.0.0       255.255.255.255 H 0 ppp0
```

The destination address of this route matches the destination address of the datagram, so `PITR2` forward this datagram via `ppp0`.
The message `interface ppp0 is not broadcast, skipping ARP` means that PPP doesn't support ARP protocol because there isn't possibility to send a message to all other nodes via PPP. Usually, ARP is used to obtain a MAC address of a node knowing its IP address and broadcast is necessary to achieve this goal.
It is difficult to propose a solution without the full topology and all routes of routers. However, I suggest verifying that the desired router has an interface with `192.168.0.254` address (defined in section `ifconfig:` of its `*.irt` file).
**EDIT** The problem is probably caused by using `++` operator in gates in your `.ned` files. The entry 
 
`PITR2.pppg++ <--> ppLink <--> lispRouter4.pppg++;`
means that in order to connect `PITR2` with `lispRouter4`, in `PITR2` **the next** `pppg` port is created and used, for example `pppg[2]` with name `ppp2`. And **we do not know the exact index** of this port because it depends on the order of creating connections in `.ned` file. 
**Proposed solution:** Revise your `.ned` files and:

1. In `.ned` of your router you probably have something like `inout pppg[]`. Change it into `inout pppg[5]` where instead of 5 write the desired number of `ppp` ports of that router (according to your network topology). Number in square brackets is the size of this port.
2. In `.ned` of your network change each connection definition which uses `pppg++` into something like this: 
   `PITR2.pppg[0] <--> ppLink <--> lispRouter4.pppg[2];` 
   Remember that you can't use two times the same index of port in the same router, and the index can't exceed total size of the port minus one.
3. Modify your routing tables in `.irt` files according to the indexes of port you have made in previous point. The name of port `pppg[X]` is `pppX`.

Comment: I think this might be the full topology you asked for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31525065/omnet-inet-how-to-adjust-routing-files-when-adding-components-to-a-ned-scena